# Read output from a Python Executed Script

Tags: python, loops, operating-system, output, computer-forensics

I am currently creating a program to extract file from drives. I would like to ask how I read an output that is displayed using python shell? For example:

```
while i<len(drives):
    print 'Searching for file in:', drives[i]
    print ''
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(drives[i]):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".vmdk"):
                print os.path.join(root, file)
            if file.endswith(".vbox"):
                print os.path.join(root,file)
    i+=1
```

I would like to read the output of `print os.path.join(root,file)` input this to another command. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how you can capture the output of `print os.path.join(root, file)`, but you could also save the output of the call to `os.path.join(root,file)` in a variable before printing. Then you can use this variable to call your command. E.g:

```
while i<len(drives):
    print 'Searching for file in:', drives[i]
    print ''
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(drives[i]):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".vmdk") or file.endswith(".vbox"):
                filePath = os.path.join(root, file)
                print filePath
                // call your command here using 'filePath'
    i+=1
```

Comment: Hey Thank you for the answer. Really Appreciate it (: I got another question though. What if in the os.path.join(root,file) command returns more than one file found? Thanks!

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html), `os.path.join` always returns a single value. If you want to keep track of all the paths generated in the loop you could consider using a [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).