# How do I read a prompt/output from another python script and return input?

Tags: python, testing, python-3.x

I'm looking to test a batch of python scripts made by different users. They're behaving in the same manor, asking for user input, it will be random but within a range I know ahead of time.

I want to write a script that executes each one of them, each of the scripts will give a prompt. Given the prompt, I want my script to respond accordingly. Is this even possible? How would I go about this?

I'd also like to detect errors, like the ones thrown by IDLE and log them to a file. Any ideas?

--Python 3 in use--

A similar questions was asked here, without a solution that fits my scenario [Read output from a Python Executed Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535769/read-output-from-a-python-executed-script)

Comment: Unless you have to do this with Python, it sounds like a job more suited for [`expect`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Comment: No reason to use `expect`; [`pexpect`](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is basically the same thing but with Python instead of Tcl…

Comment: Anyway, do you know about [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)? If so, what part are you stuck on? The examples show how to run a program (they may not explain about `sys.executable` to run a Python script… but if they don't, I just told you, so look it up…), how to feed it input, how to get its output. If the prompt is just asking for a single input, and you don't have to do anything different for different prompts, that's literally all you need. If you need more fancy interactivity, you need `pexpect`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm developing the script. I'll update this post, once I get it figured. Going the pexcept route, thanks for the suggestions